# Evaluating boolean expression over the columns of a matrix against the elements of a vector in R

Tags: r

I have a matrix of data, where I want to check whether or not the absolute value of each column falls within a certain range. Moreover, I would like to calculate the proportion of times it occurs across all columns. I know how to do this manually but I would like to write this generally outside of a loop so that any time the user gives me a matrix X and y of any size that it works. The only additional piece of information is that the number of columns of X will always be the same length of y. I also would like to do this in base R if possible. Here is my R code:

```
set.seed(42)

# Made up data
x <- matrix(rnorm(27), nrow = 9)

y <- c(.2, .5, 2)



> sum(abs(x[,1]) <= y[1] & abs(x[,2]) <= y[2] & abs(x[,3]) <= y[3]) / nrow(x)
[1] 0.2222222
```

So ideally I would want something like

```
sum(abs(x) <= y) / nrow(x)
```

Comment: Please start your code with `set.seed(42)` (or some number) and then include what your expected output should be given this logic. Is your output a vector (length `nrow(x)`) a matrix (same dim as `x`), or something else?

Comment: @r2evans 0.222222 would be want I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
sum(rowSums(t(t(abs(x)) <= y)) == ncol(x)) / nrow(x)
# [1] 0.2222222
```

Walk-through:

- Unfortunately, `x > y` recycles `y` across `x`, but column-wise, so it is effectively doing `c(x[1,1] > y[1], x[2,1] > y[2], x[3,1] > y[3], x[4,1] > y[1], ...)`, which is not what we want. We can `t`ranspose `x` so that the get the correct recycling of `y` ... and then transpose it again to get it back in the same shape as `x` (not strictly required).

  ```r
  t(t(abs(x)) <= y)
  #        [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
  #  [1,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
  #  [2,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
  #  [3,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
  #  [4,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
  #  [5,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
  #  [6,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
  #  [7,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
  #  [8,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
  #  [9,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
  ```
- Now we want to know how many rows have as many `TRUE`s as `x` has columns, done with `rowSums(.) == ncol(x)`. And the sum of all of these with `sum(.)`.